# Переноска панели

Tags: mediawiki

Как можно это исправить?

- http://fortnite.sky-wiki.com

  Кто может подсказать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы забыли написать, что именно исправить..

Comment: Нельзя выбрать язык так как мешает панель!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сместить панель ниже:

```
.mw-head {margin-top: 1.6em;}
```

Панель встанет на место(к странице).

---

Также можно сделать виджет доступным добавлением `position: relative; z-index: 1;` тега center виджета.
В этом случае можно будет выбрать язык, но останется разрыв между вкладками навигации и страницей.

Comment: Спасибо. Помогло мне очень.